# If an answer suggests using another technology, but only mentions the name of that technology and some related links, is it NAA?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

Sometimes I can see some answers suggesting the OP to use another technology like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5351118), but it just contains the name of that technology and links related to that technology, is it considered as Not An Answer?

What should a minimal answer contain if it suggests the OP using another technology?

Comment: Given that the question didn't actually specify what the asker is trying to do, those answers seem reasonable ("yes, libraries Y and Z let you do that").  If the asker named a specific function they wanted to call, I'd expect an answer to show how to declare the Java native method, bind to the library, and perform any required argument marshalling (e.g., converting a Java String to a LPCSTR or whatever) -- something way more helpful for future readers.  Basically, in this specific case, I think it's the question's fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem here is the *question*; it basically asks for a tool and those kind of questions are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Note that the question is already five years old, and might be posted before these rules were in place.

To a question like this,

> Use JNA.

(without the link) would already be a valid answer. If you have the same issue as the OP and the link becomes broken, you can just Google for JNA and continue from there.

Comment: I don't agree this is a tool request, it just asks for a way to do X - in this case invoke platform specific native APIs from Java - JNI/JNA is the regular go-to solution. It is with almost certainty a duplicate however.